# How do I correctly use a variable in pandas groupby?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to ask the user for an FSA:

```
FSA_input = ''
print('Input FSA:')
input(FSA_input)
```

Then I want to display all the Walk quantities in an FSA. It works fine if I put the FSA I'm looking up directly in the argument (M9A):

```
print(df_HHE[df_HHE['SOFSA'] == 'M9A'].groupby('Walk')['CCh'].sum())
```

But if I try to use the FSA_input variable like below, it doesnt work:

```
print(df_HHE[df_HHE['SOFSA'] == FSA_input].groupby('Walk')['CCh'].sum())
```

What is the correct way to use a variable in this case?

Comment: Have you tried asserting that `FSA_input` contains the correct string? My guess is you should be using the line `FSA_input = input('Input FSA:')` instead of those first 3 lines.

Comment: Worked like a charm! I'm only a week in...lots to learn apparently!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the problem is that the code still recognizes `FSA_input` as an empty string.
Try to change in:

```
FSA_input = ''
print('Input FSA:')
FSA_input = input()
```